# How do ruby exceptions cause mutices to unlock?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, exception, mutex, synchronize

Recently, I have been working with Ruby's threads, and have uncovered a slightly unexpected behaviour.  In a critical section, calling `raise` causes the mutex to release.  I could expect this of the `synchronize` method, with its block, but it also seems to happen when `lock` and `unlock` are called separately.

For example, the code below outputs:

```
$ ruby testmutex.rb 
x sync
y sync
```

...where I'd expect `y` to be blocked until the heat death of the universe.

```
m = Mutex.new


x = Thread.new() do
  begin
    m.lock
      puts "x sync"
      sleep 5
      raise "x err"
      sleep 5
    m.unlock 
  rescue 
  end
end


y = Thread.new() do
  sleep 0.5
  m.lock
    puts "y sync"
  m.unlock 
end


x.join
y.join
```

Why is the y thread allowed to run even though the m.unlock in the x thread is never executed?

Comment: This is an interesting observation. However...what's your question? "How does this happen" in Ruby internal implementation? Why does this happen? Is it intended or a bug?

Comment: I'm curious as to quite how it's implemented, but the main issue is the cause, which I believe you have explained with much eloquence --- thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if you remove the `raise` and the `unlock` from `x` the behavior is the same. So you have a situation where the `x` thread locks the mutex, and then the thread ends, and the mutex is unlocked.

```
m = Mutex.new
Thread.new{ m.lock; p m.locked? }.join
#=> true

p m.locked?
#=> false
```

Thus we see that the situation is unrelated to `raise`. Because you have a `begin/rescue` block around your `raise`, you just exit the `x` thread 5 seconds earlier than you would have otherwise.

Presumably the interpreter keeps tracks of any mutexes locked by a thread and automatically and intentionally unlocks them when the thread dies. (I cannot back this up with source-code inspection, however. This is just a guess, based on behavior.)

Comment: Intriguing.  Inserting a `sleep` between `rescue` and `end` illustrates that nicely.

The notion of a thread releasing its locks is quite within my expectations, I guess I never expected ruby to be so clever.

Comment: You can see it in source code: [thread.c:338](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/thread.c#L338)